# Get full URL in Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Links

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I'm currently pulling all links from a webpage of choice, but the extracted URLs don't contain the full address, and instead, look like `/example/somepage` instead of `http://baseURL/example/somepage`.

Can I output the full address somehow, or do I have to concatenate the two strings?

The code used is below.

```
$url = 'http://baseURL'
$request = Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url
$request.Links | select href
```

Comment: That is they way a web page is usually structured. If the link is part of the domain it will not show the full address because it is part of the current site. Ex: `https://www.google.com` will show several links. All links that are outside of `www.google.com` will show the full link address. Any link that is part of `www.google.com` will just show the relative path. If you wanted to make all links full links, you would have to concentrate the strings. This would be a good scenario for a condition.

Comment: @jrider Are you able to show in an answer how one would concatenate the two strings? Concatenating is pretty straightforward in my testing, but I can't figure out how to do it with the piped output in the code above.

Comment: so don't use the silly pipe! [*grin*] use a foreach loop and you can easily handle as many steps as needed. it's way too easy to get tightly focused on `pipeline! pipeline! pipeline!` when that really is not a flexible way to handle many actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://baseURL'
$request = Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url
$request.Links | Select-Object @{Label='href';Expression={@{$true=$_.href;$false=$url+$_.href}[$_.href.StartsWith('http')]}}
```